# Merging overlapping (str) objects

Tags: python

The problem is the following :

I want to go from having this **set**

```py
{'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E', ..., 'U/V', 'V/W', ..., 'X/Y', ..., 'Z', ...}
```

to this set

```py
{'A/B/C/D/E', ..., 'U/V/W', ..., 'X/Y', ..., 'Z', ...}
```

where the objects A, B, C ... are just strings of characters. The output solution should be independent of the order in which the objects appears (i.e. if you scramble the objects in the set, the solution should always be the same)

In other words I want to merge overlapping objects.

Inputs of the following form cannot happen :

```py
{"A/B", "B/C", "B/D"}
{"A/B", "B/C", "C/A"}
```

There can be objects with no `'/'` in them.

Here is a partial solution I've come up with :

```py
    example={'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E','U/V', 'V/W','X/Y'}
    
    def ext_3plus(unit):
        for couple in list(itertools.combinations(list(unit),2)):
            if '/' in couple[0] and '/' in couple[1]:
                if couple[0].split('/')[0]==couple[1].split('/')[1]:
                    unit.remove(couple[0])
                    unit.remove(couple[1])
                    unit.add(couple[1].split('/')[0]+'/'+couple[0])
                if couple[0].split('/')[1]==couple[1].split('/')[0]:
                    unit.remove(couple[0])
                    unit.remove(couple[1])
                    unit.add(couple[0]+'/'+couple[1].split('/')[1])
            else: #the input can contain object not having '/'
                continue
```

There is two problems, first it does only one iteration,
the result on `{'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E','U/V', 'V/W','X/Y'}`

is :

```py
{'A/B/C', 'C/D/E', 'U/V/W', 'X/Y'}
```

Second, if I include objects containing no `'/'`, the input being `{'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E','U/V', 'V/W','X/Y','Z'}`, the result is different from the previous one :

```py
{'A/B', 'B/C/D', 'D/E', 'U/V/W', 'X/Y', 'Z'}
```

So there should be a recursive call on the first iteration etc.
How should it be done ?

Comment: You know set has no order, so you cannot rely on that. Use a list instead

Comment: There's no need for `else: continue`. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them.

Comment: What should be the output for `{"A/B", "B/C", "B/D"}`?

Comment: No need to cast the combinations to list, btw

Comment: @Dani Mesejo This cannot happen in my case, the objects are drawn from a biological dataset. The case that you states is biologically impossible

Comment: Then say in the question exactly what's possible and what isn't.

Comment: Can you have `{"A/B", "B/C", "C/A"}`?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo No this cannot happen too, btw I added a case where the set contains a string with no ```'/'```

Comment: Updated the answer to include your new example

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly this can be seen as a graph problem, and solve as such:

```
import networkx as nx

example = {'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E', 'U/V', 'V/W', 'X/Y', "Z"}

# convert each string to a and edge
# each pattern to the side of / is a node
edges = [tuple(s.split("/")) for s in example if "/" in s]

nodes = [s for s in example if "/" not in s]

# create directed graph from edges
g = nx.from_edgelist(edges, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# find each path using topological sort
runs, current = [], []
for e in nx.topological_sort(g):
    # start a new path each time a node with in-degree 0
    # in-degree 0 means it is the start of a new path
    if g.in_degree(e) == 0:
        if current:
            runs.append(current)
            current = []
    current.append(e)

if current:
    runs.append(current)

# format the result
result = ["/".join(run) for run in runs]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Z', 'U/V/W', 'X/Y', 'A/B/C/D/E']
```

If I'm not mistaken the overall complexity of this approach is `O(n)`. More on topological sorting can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

**UPDATE**

In networkx 2.6.4 use [`lexicographical_topological_sort`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.lexicographical_topological_sort.html)

Comment: If one can use networkx, one can probably also use more-itertools, might make the grouping trivial.

Comment: Probably, but I've never used it, so that is why is not in the answer

Comment: Well, a great opportunity to finally use it :-). I think [split_before](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_before) would fit here.

Comment: Yep, it works with split_before

Comment: I do appreciate you took the time, your answer is interesting, but though I do not obtain the same output with your code ```['A', 'X', 'U', 'Z/B/Y/V/C/W/D/E']```, could you also put the version with the split_before please.

Comment: You run the code I posted an gave you that?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo Yes

Comment: But you changed the input right?

Comment: I didn't. I took your code as it is. I also tried it with ```[]```instead of ```{}```, same output, and I tried it without the ```'Z'``` then I have ```['X', 'A', 'U/Y/B/V/C/W/D/E']```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce on my side

Comment: @rawtoine I updated my version of networkx and got the same problem, posted and update to the answer that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
vals = ['A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E', 'U/V', 'V/W', 'X/Y']
data = [i.split('/') for i in vals]
def paths(d, c = [], s = []):
   if not (k:=[b for a, b in data if a == d]):
      yield c+[d]
      if (t:=[a for a, b in data if a not in s+[d]]):
         yield from paths(t[0], c = [], s=s+[d])
   else:
       yield from [j for i in k for j in paths(i, c=c+[d], s=s+[d])]

vals = list(paths(data[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['U', 'V', 'W'], ['X', 'Y']]
```

It should be noted, however, that the solution above will only work on inputs that contain standard edge definitions. If the contents of `vals` can very in the number of items divided by the `/`, then you can use the solution below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, n, c = []):
       self.n, self.c = n, c
    def __contains__(self, e):
       return e[0] == self.n or e[-1] == self.n or any(e in i for i in self.c)
    def add_edge(self, e):
       if self.n != e[0] and len(e) > 1 and (m:=[i for i in self.c if i.n == e[-1]]):
          self.c = [i for i in self.c if i != m[0]]+[Node(e[0], [m[0]])]
       elif self.n == e[0]:
          if len(e) > 1 and not any(i.n == e[1] for i in self.c):
             self.c = [*self.c, Node(e[1])]
       elif (m:=[i for i in self.c if e in i]):
          m[0].add_edge(e)
       else:
          self.c = [*self.c, Node(e[0], [] if len(e) == 1 else [Node(e[1])])]
                    
vals = ['A/B/C', 'A/B', 'B/C', 'C/D', 'D/E', 'U/V', 'V/W', 'X/Y', 'K']
n = Node(None)
for i in vals:
    k = i.split('/')
    for j in range(len(k)):
        n.add_edge(k[j:j+2])

def get_paths(n, c = []):
   if not n.c:
      yield c+[n.n]
   else:
      yield from [j for k in n.c for j in get_paths(k, c+[n.n])]

final_result = [i[1:] for i in get_paths(n)]
print(final_result)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['U', 'V', 'W'], ['X', 'Y'], ['K']]
```

With the trie-style approach of class `Node`, the order of the input (`vals`) does not matter (no sort is required) and input paths of any depth can be added.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient, but you could just repeat the loop until there's nothing modified.

```
def ext_3plus(unit):
    while True:
        oldlen = len(unit)
        for couple in itertools.combinations(list(unit),2):
            if '/' in couple[0] and '/' in couple[1]:
                if couple[0].split('/')[0]==couple[1].split('/')
                    unit.remove(couple[0])
                    unit.remove(couple[1])
                    unit.add(couple[1].split('/')[0]+'/'+couple[0])
                    modified = True
                if couple[0].split('/')[1]==couple[1].split('/')[0]
                    unit.remove(couple[0])
                    unit.remove(couple[1])
                    unit.add(couple[0]+'/'+couple[1].split('/')[1])
        if len(unit) == oldlen:
            # Nothing was merged, so we're done
            break
```